# Prevent the DB2 'USING' clause from hiding fields returned by SELECT [asterisk]..?

Tags: db2, db2-400

I'm using DB2/400 v7r3. I recently found an issue with `INNER JOIN` where the `USING` clause hides fields if the `SELECT` statement uses the `*` (asterisk) to return all fields from one of the joined tables.

How do I prevent the `USING` clause from doing this..?

I do find if the `ON FIELDA=FIELDB` style is used, all field do appear correctly. But this defeats the purpose of having the `USING` clause, and its advantage of making complex joins more compact.

I cannot find anything in the documentation about this behavior:

- [Select list notation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzselectnotation.htm)
- [Joining data with the USING clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/sqlp/rbafyjoinusing.htm)

Here is an example. Both tables have three columns X, Y, and Z:

```
-- THIS ONLY RETURNS COLUMN Z
SELECT     B.*
FROM       TABLE1 AS A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B 
           USING(X, Y)

-- THIS RETURNS ALL COLUMNS, X, Y, AND Z.
SELECT     B.*
FROM       TABLE1 AS A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B
           ON A.X=B.X
           ON A.Y=B.Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working as designed...

> The result table of the join contains the columns from the USING clause first, then the columns from the first table of the join that were not in the USING clause, followed by the remaining columns from the second table of the join that were not in the USING clause. Any column specified in the USING clause cannot be qualified in the query.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzjoinedt.htm

When you use `USING` only one copy of the `named-columns` are included in the result-set.

This is what you'd want to do...

```
SELECT     X, Y, B.*
FROM       TABLE1 AS A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B 
           USING(X, Y)
```

Comment: Ahhh, perfect..!! I tried your suggestion, and it works..!! And then because I finally had a working result, I was able to further experiment more than I did previously. I tried flipping the tables around so it started with `FROM TABLE2`, and then using only `SELECT *`...and a few other combinations, even different types of joins. But it seems as if your solution is the only way. It's not the ultimate perfect `SELECT *`, but it's a heck of a lot better than typing out half a dozen `ON FOO=BAR` expressions and dozens of field names..!!